# Responsive horizontal grid with CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid, flexbox

I'm trying to make a responsive grid with boxes that are the same height but variate in length.
Those boxes need to get filled with pictures that keep the right ratio without getting stretched (example image sizes: 400x400, 600x400, 800x400,...).

I tried a couple of things:

- Bootstrap grid: Was working fine but only when there is no horizontal margin, the margin will be considered as extra width and the images will get a different height.
- Flexbox: Was also working fine, but the rows don't have the same height.
- Other css-frameworks had the same problem as the bootstrap.

I'm going for a pure CSS solution.

Is this possible? (Other methods or solutions for the problems with flexbox/css-frameworks)

[image]

Comment: Horizontal margin can be made using margin-left/right , right?

Comment: Do you have a code example to see what you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this...

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <style>
 
 .container {
 text-align: justify;
 }
 .container > div {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 *display: inline;/*for ie*/
 zoom: 1;
 }

 .container:after {
 content: "";
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

 <div><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100&text=placehold.it+rocks!/"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x100&text=placehold.it+rocks!/"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100&text=placehold.it+rocks!/"></div>
 <div><img src="http://placehold.it/150x100&text=placehold.it+rocks!/"></div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look snippet in full browser. You have to add min-width in order that the img don't go in next line.